# T-SQL help with multiple pivot / unpivot

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, pivot, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am not sure what will be the best approch pivot or unpivot.  I have following column in one table.

---

```
group1 | group2 | group3 | amtA1 | amtA2 | amtB1 | amtB2 | amtC1 | amtC1
```

---

and I need to product table like

---

```
group1
X | amtA1  | amtB1  | amtC1
Y | amtA2  | amtB2  | amtC2

group2
X | amtA1  | amtB1  | amtC1
Y | amtA2  | amtB2  | amtC2

group3
X | amtA1  | amtB1  | amtC1
Y | amtA2  | amtB2  | amtC2
```

---

I try my best however couldn't figure out.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT group1 As Group, "X" as ColType, amtA1 as ColA,  amtB1 as ColB, amtC1 as ColC
UNION
SELECT group1, "Y", amtA2,  amtB2, amtC2
UNION 
SELECT group2, "X", amtA1,  amtB1, amtC1
UNION 
SELECT group2, "Y", amtA2,  amtB2, amtC2
UNION 
SELECT group3, "X", amtA1,  amtB1, amtC1
UNION 
SELECT group3, "Y", amtA2,  amtB2, amtC2
```

You can now easily group based on the "Group" column.

although I would be having a "discussion" about table normalisation with someone in your organisation.

Comment: thank you for reply.  I figured out its now easy to group based on group row and columns.